# Rails, Solution for cities, countries, States of the entire world not with database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, geonames

I need this simply function for populate my forms with intelligent choice from

States > Country > City.

I can populate a database and I can use simply Rails's associations, but I don't want.

Is there a solution with gem using WebServices, xml and other solutions databaseless and more easy, fresh and simply?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a rubygem called `Country`.

https://github.com/hexorx/countries